# Outlook: Search for 10-digit numbers in all emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-365

I need to search an Exchange mailbox for contents in emails etc. containing a string of 10-digits in the format

- *1234567890* or
- *123456-7890*
- The number format is actually *ddmmyy-1234*, so another value could be *010199-2345*

How do I perform a search for these kind of string 10-digit numbers in Microsoft Outlook?
As a regular expression, I'd write `\d{6}(-|)\d{4}`, but Outlook doesn't seem to support this.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this, hope to help you:

[image]

Comment: Try what? Images are good, but should illustrate the solution rather than BEING the solution. Please edit your answer adding the information to the answer in text form.

Comment: I mark the field in search bar in the picture with a red box, do you have any questions?

Comment: Sorry, @Christy, but this only find the specific number - I want to search for ANY 10-digit number. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: If so, i'm afraid it can not be done in Outlook client. And as i know, strings of numbers less than five digits are ignored. If you want to search for 98101, entering 9810 will not return any results.